# Problems sending an AJAX post where the data is a simple string to ASP.NET 5 WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

My goal is to send a string to and asp.net 5 web api method and then have the method simply return a string as the result.

Here is my js:

```
    $("#btnChangeName").click(function() {
        var prodName = $("#txtProductName").val();

        var url = 'http://localhost:27081/api/products/changename';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: JSON.stringify({name: prodName}),
            success: successFuncApi,
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/functions/changename")]
    public string ChangeName([FromBody]dynamic value)
    {
        string newName = ChangeNameHelper(value.name.ToString());
        return newName;
    }
```

The strangest thing is that when I use postman or fiddler and send it something like this in the raw body:

```
{"name":"John"}
```

it works completely fine. Why doesn't it work with an AJAX request? My dynamic param ends up being null.

Is it 100% a requirement to always bind to a model in the new web api? In this case I am only dealing with a simple string in and a simple string out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to serialize your data using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

So try replacing this:

`data: {name: name}`

with this:

`data: JSON.stringify({name: name})`

JSON is available with modern browsers. But if you need to support IE8, or where your browser does not support it, you need to include [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

**UPDATE**

@Blake, here's my response to your comment: *It is too long to put in the comment section.*

I have not used `dynamic` to receive a complex type into my Web APIs before. However, I have used [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm). Then you can access the `name` property like this:

```
public string ChangeName([FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
{
     var name = jsonbody.Value<string>("name");
     ...
}
```

Comment: I tried using JSON.stringify and my [FromBody]dynamic value is still null. I updated my post to show what I currently have. For some reason in the new ASP.NET Web API I feel like you have to use model binding. I am trying to bypass this and simply send a single string to the method in my controller and return a simple string. It is very weird that when I send the request through fiddler it works. It actually created a dynamic object where I can simply call myObj.name to get the value.

Comment: Hmm in my vs solution I have an asp.net web mvc project and an asp.net web api project. I think the problem is that the mvc project is running under localhost:57068 and the web api project is running under localhost:27081 and I believe the browser isn't allowing the AJAX request across sites.

Comment: The cross sites issue had to do with Chrome and for now I don't feel like dealing with it so I just added a Controllers/api folder to the same project. It is very strange that my view model is still not binding. It is always null.

Comment: @BlakeRivell, see my update. Sorry for the delay. I'm from Oz.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I figured out what my problem was. I wasn't specifying the contentType as application/json so the data wasn't getting passed to the web api properly. With a combination of application/json as the contentType and JSON.stringify it worked! Thanks for letting me know about JSON.stringify.

Comment: @BlakeRivell, your original question had the contetType parameter so I did not mention it. I didn't realise you deleted it from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create an object to send the string. This will work.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/functions/changename")]
public string ChangeName([FromBody]string value)
{
    string newName = ChangeNameHelper(value=);
    return newName;
}
```

The trick is to send a ***JSON*** string, not just a string. They are not the same.

```
$("#btnChangeName").click(function() {
    var prodName = $("#txtProductName").val();

    var url = 'http://localhost:27081/api/products/changename';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        contentType:'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(prodName),
        success: successFuncApi,
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```